# Use partials as in SCSS

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

**main.js** (inspired by SCSS)

```
@include "partial1";
@include "partial2";
```

**partial1.js**

```
function popUp(text){
   window.alert(text);
}
```

**partial2.js**

```
function log(text){
   console.log(text);
}
```

**What I want to achieve**

Using Atom, when I save *main.js*, a file called *main.min.js* should be created which compiles the content of all "imported" scripts and be minified:

```
function popUp(o){window.alert(o)}function log(o){console.log(o)}
```

**Why?**

I try to simplify live development. When a developer loads the page, the "partials" are loaded directly. If a non-developer loads the page, *main.min.js* gets loaded. As soon as the partial scripts are tested, the developer can open *main.js* and save it, to update *main.min.js*.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question? This might be better suited for the Code Review stackexchange site

Comment: @RobM. How to get this to work. The content of *main.js* is just pseudo code and doesn't work.

Comment: This idea already exists (minus the SCSS style `@include`), have you looked at Babel + Webpack? They can accomplish this already, though they use `import package from './module'` syntax

Comment: You'd have to make a parser to 'put together' your partials from `main.js` pseudo code

Comment: @RobM. I've just checked it. My partial files contain only functions. I'd like to import just the content and not export each function one-by-one.

Comment: @AquilaSagitta May you provide me with an example for that?

Comment: writing a parser isn't trivial. Google around, quick search I found [this short tutorial](https://medium.com/@daffl/beyond-regex-writing-a-parser-in-javascript-8c9ed10576a6)